# The name parameter 'Child' isn't defined for BottomAppBar() widget

Tags: flutter

I'm currently trying to construct a bottom app bar for my flutter. I am new to the BottomAppBar widget and as I concurrently referred to the documentation while making the code, I've stumbled upon this error.

The following image shows the error

![BottomAppBar]: https://ibb.co/Bn3hKFN

Comment: please paste code here only not as an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that your class name the same as the widget name **BottomAppBar**

You need to change the class name to

```
class BottomAppBarImpl extends StatelessWidget{

/*

/// Put Your code Here it starts working fine

/*

}
```

Comment: If it resolves the issue please accept and upvote the answer